# very basic animation using CGPointmake and NSSTimer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, nstimer

I watched a tutorial on YouTube about making a Flappy Bird clone. The code used `CGPointMake()` with an integer variable and a timer to move the bird up and down the screen, but the code I've copied does not cause the bird to move.

Viewcontroller.h

```
int BirdFlight;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *Bird;
    IBOutlet UIButton *StartGame;

    NSTimer *BirdMovement;
}

- (IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender;
-(void)BirdMoving;

@end
```

Viewcontroller.m (all changes)

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender{
    StartGame.hidden = YES;
    BirdMovement  = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self
                                          selector:@selector(BirdMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)BirdMoving {

    Bird.center = CGPointMake(Bird.center.x, Bird.center.y - BirdFlight);
    BirdFlight = BirdFlight - 5;

    if (BirdFlight < -15) {
        BirdFlight = -15;
    }

    if (BirdFlight > 0) {
        Bird.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BirdUp.png"];      
    }

    if (BirdFlight < 0) {
        Bird.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    BirdFlight = 30;
}
```

I don't want to use any other method to animate I'm just wondering how to make the code work like in the video. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKG6fsM5JiA)

Comment: Since you're just starting out, get used to using the correct naming conventions. Properties, variables, and method names should start with a lowercase letter. Class names with upper case. Also, there's no need to put any variables, properties or method signatures in the .h file unless you want to expose them to other classes. If they're for internal (to the class) use, then put properties and method names in a class extension at the top of the .m file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self
                          selector:@selector(BirdMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

should be

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(BirdMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: oh got thanks. Can you tell me the difference please.

Comment: Oops yeah I just noticed it was a variable sorry about that. You tried the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval and it didn't work?

Comment: Is your StartGame method getting called? If not that means you may not have linked the action in interface builder.

Comment: no I noticed the scheduled. and it works perfectly. I guess I missed it in the video Can you tell me the difference please

Comment: The previous example just creates the timer but doesn't tell it to run.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it works :) Also just want to let you know that if you alt-click on a method in Xcode it will tell you what the method does so it will make learning easier.